# Understanding nagios check_ping plugin output

Tags: output, nagios

Trying to understand the output of Nagios Plugin check_ping:

```
root@debian:/usr/local/nagios/libexec# ./check_ping -H 192.168.234.135 -w 10,1% -c 20,10%
PING CRITICAL - Packet loss = 60%, RTA = 1.26 ms|rta=1.256000ms;10.000000;20.000000;0.000000 pl=60%;1;10;0
root@debian:/usr/local/nagios/libexec#
```

As per the [documentation](http://nagios.manubulon.com/traduction/docs25en/perfdata.html), the performance data is displayed after the pipe '|' symbol. I am trying to understand the fourth parameter for each category / section. In the above example, what does 0.000000 and 0 stands for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, here is the official documentation: [Nagios Plugin Development Guidelines](https://nagios-plugins.org/doc/guidelines.html#AEN200)

Second, the numbers returned from each metric (in order) is:

value [with unit of measurement], warning threshold, critical threshold, minimum value, maximum value

In your case, only the warning,critical and minimum are reported after the perfdata itself. So to answer your question, those numbers are the minimum value (possible).

Comment: Thanks. Is there any scenario where the minimum value could be anything other than a 0 (for check_ping plugin)?

Comment: You can't get any ping response less than 0, unless you're in alternate universe where time is meaningless.